# SQL query to add a value x in a column if a column has Y value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
Machine ID     Hostname     IP Address
1              Test 1       10.216.x.x
2              Test 2       10.218.x.x
3              Test 3       172.21.x.x
5              Test 4       192.25.x.x
```

I need to add a column where 10.216.x.x segment will be Chennai and 192.25.X.X will be Delhi etc

```
Machine ID     Hostname     IP Address    Location
1              Test 1       10.216.x.x    Chennai
2              Test 2       10.218.x.x    Mumbai
3              Test 3       172.21.x.x    NOIDA
5              Test 4       192.25.x.x    Delhi
```

SQL Server 2008 R2..

How can we get this in a query?

Comment: Declare the column as a `CASE` expression, documented [here for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) and [here for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: It seems like you may have 255*255 locations you may need to manage over time.  I'd create a lookup table for the first two octets and do simple joins.  A case statement could get unwieldy over time.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, do include your work.

Comment: Can you please explain? I am completely new to this.

Comment: @Karthek  Something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/423bd/1/0.  This way you don't have to add a new case statemetn to the SQL every time.  Instead you just add data to a table.  The way this is written you can go to any octet and define location.  The IPLocation table just has to be updated for new IP's.  I believe this to be better programatically as you don't have to change the select, you update data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/888b7/1/0)):

```
SELECT [Machine ID], Hostname, [IP Address], 
CASE WHEN [IP Address] LIKE '10.216%' THEN 'Chennai'
     WHEN [IP Address] LIKE '10.218%' THEN 'Mumbai'
     WHEN [IP Address] LIKE '172.21%' THEN 'NOIDA'
     WHEN [IP Address] LIKE '192.25%' THEN 'Delhi'
     ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: This worked well for me. Thank you so much for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Machine ID]     
      ,Hostname     
      ,[IP Address]
      ,CASE 
           WHEN LEFT([IP Address] , 6) = '10.216' THEN 'Chennai'
           WHEN LEFT([IP Address] , 6) = '10.218' THEN 'Mumbai'
           WHEN LEFT([IP Address] , 6) = '192.25' THEN 'Delhi'
           WHEN LEFT([IP Address] , 6) = '172.21' THEN 'NOIDA'
       END AS [Location]
FROM Table_Name
```

Comment: I get values as Null in the column Location.

Comment: Sorry my bad I was selecting left 5 values it should have be left 6 values. try again and it should work. cheers

Comment: It worked.. Thank you.. Can i know what is this 5 and 6?

Comment: its a SQL Server string function `LEFT(ColumnName, Integer)`, it takes two arguments, a string and an integer value and returns you number of characters equal to that integer from that string. google it to learn more :)